# Subtract subsequent elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list like $ \{1, 2, 7, 8, 10, 11, 16, 17\} $, I want to create a new one subtracting the number in the $ n-th $ position to the number in the $ (n+1)-th $ position, so the new list will be $ \{1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1\} $.

Comment: If `alist = {1, 2, 7, 8, 10, 11, 16, 17}` then `Differences[alist]` would give the desired result.

Comment: Start with the `Guide` for [`List Manipulation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Another option:**

```
list={1, 2, 7, 8, 10, 11, 16, 17};
Delete[list,1]-Delete[list,-1]
```

Comment: Or `Rest[list] - Most[list]`